# Unable to verify the Signature with two different mechanism

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I have two clients,

1. first client expect CMS/PKCS to verify signature
2. second client expect only signature (EncryptedDigestMessage). Original file  and certificate separately to verify signature

So, I want to create one method that should return the appropriate output based on format (PKCS or SignOnly)

```
public static byte[] digitalSign(byte[] fileContent , PrivateKey privkey , X509Certificate x509Certificate , String format) throws Exception{

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
        CMSTypedData data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(fileContent);
        certList.add(x509Certificate);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("MD5WithRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privkey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(sha1Signer,x509Certificate));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(data, true);
        
        //based on the format this method should return expected byte[]
        if(format.equals("PKCS")){//should return CMS/PKCS package
            return signedData.getEncoded();
        }else{//should return only Signature (Encrypted Digest of fileContent)
            SignerInformation signer = signedData.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next();
            return signer.getSignature();// returns the Signature
        }
    }
```

I verified PKCS using below method. signature is verified
it returns true.

```
//CMS/PKCS signature verification
    public static boolean verfySignaturePKCS(byte[] cmsSignedBytes ) throws Exception{
        boolean result = false;
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        CMSSignedData cms =new CMSSignedData(cmsSignedBytes );
        Store<X509CertificateHolder> certificates = cms.getCertificates();
        
        SignerInformationStore signerInfos = cms.getSignerInfos();
        Collection<SignerInformation> signers = signerInfos.getSigners();
        Iterator<SignerInformation> iterator = signers.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
            SignerInformation signer = iterator.next(); 
            Collection<X509CertificateHolder> certCollection = certificates.getMatches(signer.getSID()); 
            Iterator<X509CertificateHolder> certIt = certCollection.iterator(); 
            X509CertificateHolder certHolder = certIt.next(); 
            X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);
            
            if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))) {
                result = true; 
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

To verify that SignOnly data, I'm using normal Java security `MessageDigest` and `Cipher` classes.

parameters:

1. signedData--> Signature
2. fileBytes--> Original File content
3. cert--> X509Certificate to decrypt the signature

method process:

1. generate messageHash from original file content
2. decrypt Signature with cert and get the decryptedMessageHash
3. compare messageHash and decryptedMessageHash

In this way decrypt signature is going well without error. So I understand this is correct signature which is signed by my privatekey related to the given certificate.
but, both messageHash and decryptedMessageHash  having different data.

```
    public static boolean verifySignOnly(byte[] signedData,byte[] fileBytes ,X509Certificate cert) throws Exception{
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5" , "BC");
        byte[] messageHash = md.digest(fileBytes);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA" , "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, cert);
        byte[] decryptedMessageHash = cipher.doFinal(signedData);
        return Arrays.equals(decryptedMessageHash, messageHash);
        
    }
```

Can anyone explain what mistake I made?

Comment: Please add only a [mcve].

Comment: MD5withRSA is an instance of the original PKCS1v1 signature scheme, now (in v2) retronymed [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-8.2). Even in RSA, sign and verify are NOT 'encrypt and decrypt the hash' as was briefly but wrongly thought last century, and unfortunately baked into Java history which is why the semantically defective `Cipher.getInstance("RSA").init(ENCRYPT,private) and (DECRYPT,public)` work. See numerous Qs and As on security.SX and crypto.SX about this. ...

Comment: ... In particular SSA-PKCS1-v1_5 does (and undoes) _two_ kinds of padding (ASN.1 DigestInfo and 01FF...00) but that Java Cipher only does the latter so you must do the former yourself -- which amounts to a fixed prefix depending on the hash algorithm, as shown in note 1 of section 9.2. (ninja) Alternatively use the Java `Signature` class with `.getInstance("MD5withRSA")` which does the whole job (_including_ the hash) correctly. PS: MD5 has been totally broken for collision for years, and thus is insecure for signature in many cases.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks a lot.Great help!!. Now i'm going to use `Signature` class for Sign and verification for "SignOnly" type.